# Gerando um Arquivo novo com um template em Excel ao Salvar

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia,
meu software trabalha com leitura de codigo de barras para geração de etiquetas impressas. Tem varios Texbox , cada um recebendo do leitor um codigo diferente. Ao clicar em Salvar ele manda esses codigos para uma planilha Excel onde eu posso imprimir e anexar na caixa com os produtos.Só que eu só consegui fazer com que toda vez que fosse clicado em Salvar, ele sobrescrevesse um template , no caso para a formatação e  nome da empresa sairem organizados, só que quando há erro "B.O", ao envés de procurar pelo arquivo em xls referentes aquelas etiquetas, é preciso re-bipar pois o arquivo não existe, já que ele sempre vai sobrescrever o anterior, tem como Clicar em Salvar , e toda vez ele gerar um novo arquivo, referenciando com o numero da caixa que é preenchida em um texbox ?

```
//Criando arquivo no Excel.exe:
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\EtiqMasterBoxTornozeleira.xlsx");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = Excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
        Excel.Range userRanger = x.UsedRange;

        int countRecords = userRanger.Rows.Count;
        int add = countRecords + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [SaveAs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff841185.aspx) do Excel.Workbook para salvar com outro nome, assim você só vai utilizar o EtiqMasterBoxTornozeleira.xlsx como template.

Vai ficar algo assim:

```
sheet.SaveAs(string.Format("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\{0}.xlsx", suaEtiqueta));
```

Comment: oque eu teria que passar como informação nesse campo  "suaEtiqueta" ?

Comment: @LuizFelipe, nesse lugar que você vai está passando o nome único do seu arquivo, o nome que vai ser criado o .xlsx. Lembrando que tem que ser uma string =]

Comment: mais uma duvida, coloquei o código acima assim: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = sheet.SaveAs(string.Format("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\{0}.xlsx", "tornozeleira"));` estaria certo dessa maneira ?, aqui ele apresentou erro @Brunno, tentei passar o nome do meu arquivo em excel mas ele apresenta erro.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, o método SaveAs() ele é void, não retorna nada. O correto é depois que você finalizar tudo, tiver setado os valores chamar ele para gerar o arquivo. A chamada deve ser igual a exibida acima =]